# Insert data into mutiple tables of PostgreSQL using grape API?

Tags: ruby, json, postgresql, grape-api

Here is my grape API Ruby code which inserts JSON data posted to it into a single table:

```
  class Posts < Grape::API

  version 'v1', :using => :path
  format :json

  resource 'posts' do
    get "/" do
      Post.all
    end

    get "/:id" do 
      Post.find(params['id'])
    end

    post "/create" do
      Post.create(params['post'])
    end
  end

end
```

How can I insert data into multiple tables using the grape API? I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: How do you insert data without Grape?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly.

For creating multiple posts, you would either:

- call your API several times
- need to write something like a batch import

For the first option, your problem is on the client-side, as you need to issue e.g. 10 x requests with Curl.

For the latter, you both need to develop a collection format on the client-side (e.g. JSON [ {..}, {..}, .. ], and then process the collection format in your API.